# Lightweight tool for designing a user interface for javascript programs

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I'm applying for a software development job and I want to answer some of the programming questions using javascript. The focus of the questions is how the code is implemented, algorithm used, etc, but I want to also design a simple but elegant UI to go "the extra mile".

In the past I've used Microsoft's Script Editor to build a basic HTML interface using forum components. Alas, MSE no longer comes with Office, and I can't access an older version.

I'm looking for any solution that lets me quickly build a simple, web-based UI whose components can easily integrate with JavaScript using either standard DOM or an included library. I'd also like a portable solution so I can put it on my flash drive. I've been using WebStorm for my API, and really like it, but don't want to keep having to design a UI from a text editor.

Comment: I'd get used to the text editor... less bloat, and you know exactly what your components are... (just an opinion tho!)

Comment: Just to be clear, are any and all text editors (anywhere between WordPad, up to Sublime - my favorite so far - up to Webstorm and beyond) out of the question?

Comment: I have about of experience using a text editor for UX design. I developed a full client application using  only notepad and IE in a closed system. Because of this I also know how long it can take. I'm looking for a simple solution that will let me focus my programming on answering the questions while still having a basic, functional UI.